# Snakemake optional filter rule

Tags: snakemake

I use the following sequence of Snakemake rules for sequencing data.

QC -> Quality filtering -> (Taxonomic filtering) -> Assembly
QC -> Quality filtering -> Assembly

Taxonomic filtering is activated by the user via the config file.
How to implement this ?

I tried via conditional statements inside run blocks. However, this prevents the use of conda environments and creates symbolic links.

What would be best practice to implement optional rules in a sequence?

```
config["use-taxon-filter"] = True

## Mandatory quality filter
rule quality_filter:
    input:
        fw="input/forward.fastq",
        rv="input/reverse.fastq"
    output:
        fw="results/qc_filter/forward.fastq",
        rv="results/qc_filter/reverse.fastq"
    shell:
        """
            qual_filter {input.fw} {input.rv} -out {output}
        """    

## Optional filtering with kraken
## Either real filter or symbolic links are created
rule taxon-filter:
    input:
        fw="results/qc_filter/forward.fastq",
        rv="results/qc_filter/reverse.fastq"
    output:
        fw="results/processed/forward.fastq",
        rv="results/processed/reverse.fastq"
    run:
        if(config.get("use-kraken-filter")):
            kraken-filter.py {input.fw} {input.rv} -out {output}
        else:
            os.symlink(output.fw, input.fw)
            os.symlink(output.rv, input.rv)
              


rule assembly:
    input:
        fw="results/processed/forward.fastq",
        rv="results/processed/reverse.fastq"
    output:
        "results/assemblies/assembly.fasta"
    shell:
        """
           spades {input.fw} {output.rv} {output}
        """
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an conditional in the input or a function.

```py
config["use-taxon-filter"] = True

## Mandatory quality filter
rule quality_filter:
    input:
        fw="input/forward.fastq",
        rv="input/reverse.fastq"
    output:
        fw="results/qc_filter/forward.fastq",
        rv="results/qc_filter/reverse.fastq"
    shell:
        """
            qual_filter {input.fw} {input.rv} -out {output}
        """    

## Optional filtering with kraken
## Either real filter or symbolic links are created
rule taxon_filter:
    input:
        fw="results/qc_filter/forward.fastq",
        rv="results/qc_filter/reverse.fastq"
    output:
        fw="results/processed/forward.fastq",
        rv="results/processed/reverse.fastq"
    run:
        if(config.get("use-kraken-filter")):
            kraken-filter.py {input.fw} {input.rv} -out {output}
        else:
            os.symlink(output.fw, input.fw)
            os.symlink(output.rv, input.rv)
              

def get_assembly_input_rv():
    if config["use-taxon-filter"]:
        return "results/qc_filter/reverse.fastq"
    else:
        return "results/processed/reverse.fastq"

rule assembly:
    input:
        # inline conditional
        fw=rules.taxon_filter.output.fw if config["use-taxon-filter"] else rules.quality_filter.output.fw,
        # input function
        rv=get_assembly_input_rv,
    output:
        "results/assemblies/assembly.fasta"
    shell:
        """
           spades {input.fw} {output.rv} {output}
        """
```

(code untested)

Note the rename `taxon-filter` to `taxon_filter`. I don't think a dash ("-") in a rule name represents a valid rule name.